# laravel CI / CD Development

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, aws-codebuild, cicd

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the Laravel CI/CD Development in code commit AWS?

I have gone through a lot of tutorials but always fail to connect the Database to either elastic beanstalk or EC2,
Can someone recommend a good tutorial for this

This is my build Command.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
   install:
     runtime-versions:
         php: 7.4
         nodejs: 12.x
     commands:
         - apt-get update -y
         - apt-get install -y libpq-dev libzip-dev
         - apt-get install -y php-pgsql
         - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
   pre_build:
     commands:
         - cp .env.beta .env
         - composer install
         - npm install
   build:
     commands:
         - npm run production
         - php artisan migrate --force
         - php artisan db:seed
artifacts:
   files:
         - '**/*'
   name: $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S).zip
proxy:
   upload-artifacts: yes
   logs: yes
```

now i am getting ngnix 404 error,Even after adding " /public " in beanstalk